# About defining arrays later

Tags: objective-c

```
float bases[7];
if (level < 2) {
    bases = {80, 70, 50, 20, 10, 2 , 1};
}else{
    bases = {100, 100, 80, 50, 25, 6, 3};
}
```

This is not valid. But then, what is the right way to do it?

Comment: That is not Objective C. It is C.

Comment: @matt: Yeah, it's C. But I wouldn't say it isn't Objective-C.

Comment: ObjC is an extension of C, hence this is valid ObjC.

Comment: It is valid but the tag and title suggest this q is about Objective C arrays.

Comment: Why declare float if all values are int?

Comment: @matt: Because the values of the array are modified in the future - and the result of those modifications can be floats.

Answer (score 1):

You could try just copying the data over, either element by element, or with:

```
float bases[7];
static float *bases1 = {80,70,50,20,10,2,1};
static float *bases2 = {100,100,80,50,25,6,3};
if (level < 2)
    memcpy (bases, bases1, sizeof(bases));
else
    memcpy (bases, bases2, sizeof(bases));
```

Comment: @matt, because they're static and you may want to copy in the _original_ data again at some point in the future. I tried as much as possible to duplicate the (apparent) intent of the asker's code. If you simply use `float *bases = bases2;` followed by `bases[3] = 3.14159f;`, you'll lose that capacity - the `50` in `bases2` will no longer be fifty.